# Why can't I access Whitehouse.Gov with the IP address or the Aliases?

Tags: ip-address, dns

I'm studying the basics of networking at the moment, and I was testing out what I had learned when I discovered that I could not access WhiteHouse.gov via the IP address.

After using `dig` on WhiteHouse.gov, I was returned this:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.whitehouse.gov. 252 IN  CNAME   wildcard.whitehouse.gov.edgekey.net.
wildcard.whitehouse.gov.edgekey.net. 307 IN CNAME e4036.dscb.akamaiedge.net.
e4036.dscb.akamaiedge.net. 20   IN  A   104.96.239.25
```

I then attempted to access https://e4036.dscb.akamaiedge.net and https://104.96.239.25. Both queries returned the following error:

> Invalid URL.
> The requested URL "[no URL]", is invalid.
> Reference #9.26dc6068.1614052207.40f6272

Why did this happen? Shouldn't both have resolved to the White House website? To ensure my network was working, I tried the normal WhiteHouse.gov url, and it works fine.

If direct IP access was blocked for security reasons, what exactly are those security reasons? What harm could someone pose directly accessing the IP?

Comment: The response you received is from the site, which demonstrates that you did resolve the name. But application protocols are off topic here as well as questions about networks you don’t control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is "name based virtual hosting".

As the web started to get off the ground, people wanted to put multiple hostnames on the same webserver, some declared such names to be "vanity" but it quickly became apparent that this was something people were going to do.

Initially this was done by allocating the webserver multiple IP addresses, but this was seen as wasteful, so "name based virtual hosting" was introduced allowing multiple hostnames to be served different content from the same IP through the addition of an extra header in the http request. Initially this was an optional extension but it became a mandatory part of the http spect with the introduction of http 1.1.

Initially most webservers would have a "default" website that was served when no host header was present or an unknown value was present in the host header. Many still do, but it's becoming increasingly common to have servers that serve up a whole bunch of unrelated websites, so there is no sensible "default" to set.